# Apache 2.2.21 installation on Linux 6 but got error while accessing in browser

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I am very new to linux.
I have installed apache 2.2.21 on linux 6 platform. While I am using `./apachectl start` or `./apachectl -k start` command it shows that apache is started. But while i am trying to access apache default page in any browser using `http://<servername>:8080`
it shows page cannot be displayed.

Can any one help me on this issue? Please its urgent.

I am also enclosing the error_log file as below.

error_log file:

```
[Thu Nov 24 08:57:23 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 01:45:58 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 01:46:12 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 01:46:12 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 01:46:13 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 01:54:58 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 01:55:10 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 01:55:10 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 01:55:11 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 01:58:10 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 01:59:41 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 01:59:41 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 01:59:42 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 03:23:14 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 03:27:36 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 03:27:36 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 03:27:37 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 08:52:27 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 08:52:43 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 08:52:43 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 08:52:44 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 25 09:21:39 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 25 09:21:57 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 25 09:21:57 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Nov 25 09:21:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 28 01:06:58 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Nov 28 01:07:58 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Nov 28 01:07:58 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Nov 28 01:07:59 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: http://:8080 ??? why is there port 8080 standart is 80 and what kind of adres is that ? you should put http://yourdomain.com or your ip

Comment: Linux 6? I believe time machine is not yet invented. Latest version of Linux is 3. You are talking about RHEL/CentOS version 6. Please correct it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the error log that you provided that suggests there is any problem, with apache running.

Have you really configured your system to [**listen**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) on port 8080? Check the Listen statement in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` it should be something like

```
Listen 8080
```

if you have. If it says

```
Listen 80
```

Then apache is listening on the standard port and you can contact it with `http://<servername>`.

Edit:

Assuming Linux 6 means RHEL6 or CentOS6 then you most likely haven't opened port 8080 on your firewall.You can open port 8080 with the following command

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If that works then don't forget to save the firewall configuration with

```
service iptables save
```

Comment: yes the listening port is 8080.

Comment: i have also checked http://<my_servername>:8080 but in the browser it shows page cannot be displayed.

Comment: Check your firewall is allowing traffic on port 8080 - see my edit.

Comment: i have the firewall is not running on , that means port 8080 is allowable,but still i am unable to access apache in web browser.

Comment: In that case your problem lies elsewhere.